# tikz building blocks for pneumatic diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

I've created a small library of tikz shapes that I want to use over and over in a convienient manner. The following is a subset of the shapes used together in an example:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}

\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%Left-override
\begin{scope}[rotate=270]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,-2.5) --(3,-2.5)--(3,0);
\draw (0.25,-2.25)--(1.5,-1)--(2.75,-2.25)--cycle;
\end{scope}
%horz-3by2solenoid
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,1)},rotate=270]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,5) -- (5,5) -- (5,0) -- (0,0);
\draw[line width = 0.1cm,black] (5,1.25) -- (4,1.25);
\draw[line width = 0.1cm,black] (4,1.75) -- (4,.75);
\draw[-{Triangle},line width = 0.1cm,blue] (5,2.5) -- (0,2);
\draw[-{Triangle},line width = 0.1cm,red] (0,3.25) -- (5,3.75);
\draw (0,5) -- (0,10) -- (5,10) -- (5,5) -- (0,5);
\draw[line width = 0.1cm,black] (5,8.75) -- (4,8.75) node[pos=-0.5]{EB};
\draw[line width = 0.1cm,black] (4,9.25) -- (4,8.25);
\draw[-{Triangle},line width = 0.1cm,blue] (0,6.75) -- (5,6.25)node[pos=1.1]{EA};
\draw[-{Triangle},line width = 0.1cm,red] (5,7.5) -- (0,8) node[pos=-0.1]{S};
\end{scope}
%Right-override
\begin{scope}[shift={(10,-3)},rotate=90]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,-2.5) --(3,-2.5)--(3,0);
\draw (0.25,-2.25)--(1.5,-1)--(2.75,-2.25)--cycle;
\end{scope}
%Right-coil
\begin{scope}[shift={(12.5,-3)},rotate=90]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,-2.5) --(3,-2.5)--(3,0);
\draw (0,-1.5)--(3,-1);
\end{scope}
%some connection lines..
\draw[green](2,1.5)--(2,4)--(20,4);
\draw[green](3,1.5)--(3,3)--(18,3)--(18,-7)--(20,-7);
\draw[green](3.75,-4.25)--(3.75,-5.5);
%Vertical-2wayPiston
\begin{scope}[shift={(20,-12.5)}]
\draw (1,5) -- (1,19) -- (5,19) -- (5,5) -- (1,5);
\draw (0,17) -- (1,17);
\draw (0,6) -- (1,6);
\filldraw (1,15) rectangle (5,16);
\filldraw[fill=white] (2.9,15) rectangle (3.1,1);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(20,-12.5)}]
\draw[{Triangle}-{Triangle},line width = 0.1cm] (7,10)--node[pos=1.1]{OPEN}(7,15);
\end{scope}
%Vertical-speedControl
\begin{scope}[shift={(3.75,-9)},scale=0.75]
\draw (0,4)--(0,3);
\draw (0,1)--(0,0);
\draw (1,0.5) arc (-90:-270:0.9 and 1.5);
\draw (-1,0.5) arc (-90:90:0.9 and 1.5);
\draw [-{Triangle}](-1,1) -- (1,3);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

that produces the following image:

[image]

What would be the easiest way to cobble these building blocks together such that drawing the green lines would be easier? I purposely did not connect them to the intended locations to illustrate difficulty... But I would like them to join up at the obvious spots.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Name the coordinates and then draw between them? What's the problem exactly?

Comment: In TikZ nomenclature, a shape is a type of node (by default, nodes are rectangles).  You can create shapes, although it is a lot easier with circuitikz than TikZ.

Comment: @JohnKormylo `pic`s are easier. Not sure how `circuittikz` would make creating new node types easier. Does it provide a higher level interface? There is another package which does that, I think, but the nodes are not as flexible as arbitrary Ti*k*Z nodes, I think.

Comment: On a side, suggest to use `\def` and `\tikzmath` to automate your code better

Comment: @cfr I've been using Tex for decades, but only recently started using tikz instead of inserting jpg or eps graphics. Coordinates, as shown in solution proposed by StefanH should do the trick.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I suppose calling them shapes is because I have full intention of defining shapes with anchors as part of this learning experience so that I can grow larger diagrams with the ease of using a package like circuitikz.

Comment: @cfr - First, TikZ shapes normally change size when you add text.  Second, for bipoles at least most of the work is done by the \pgfcircdeclarebipole macro.  Lastly, TikZ was written using plain TeX (for comparibility).  So it is easier to copy and modify circuitikz shapes than TikZ shapes.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks. I don't understand the explanation, but that's just my ignorance, no doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `coordinate`s at the points you want to connect and use them to draw the lines. I also added the library `calc` to draw the lines. They can also be used to position your blocks, as e.g. the `speed control`:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}

\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc} %%% Add calc

\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Left-override
  \begin{scope}[rotate=270]
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,-2.5) --(3,-2.5)--(3,0);
    \draw (0.25,-2.25)--(1.5,-1)--(2.75,-2.25)--cycle;
  \end{scope}
  % horz-3by2solenoid
  \begin{scope}[shift={(0,1)},rotate=270]
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,5) -- (5,5) -- (5,0) -- (0,0);
    \draw[line width = 0.1cm,black] (5,1.25) -- (4,1.25);
    \draw[line width = 0.1cm,black] (4,1.75) -- (4,.75);
    \draw[-{Triangle},line width = 0.1cm,blue] (5,2.5) -- (0,2) coordinate(BlueArrow);   %%% New coordinate
    \draw[-{Triangle},line width = 0.1cm,red] (0,3.25) -- (5,3.75) 
    coordinate[pos=0](RedArrowStart) coordinate[pos=1](RedArrowEnd);  %%% New coordinates
    \draw (0,5) -- (0,10) -- (5,10) -- (5,5) -- (0,5);
    \draw[line width = 0.1cm,black] (5,8.75) -- (4,8.75) node[pos=-0.5]{EB};
    \draw[line width = 0.1cm,black] (4,9.25) -- (4,8.25);
    \draw[-{Triangle},line width = 0.1cm,blue] (0,6.75) -- (5,6.25)node[pos=1.1]{EA};
    \draw[-{Triangle},line width = 0.1cm,red] (5,7.5) -- (0,8) node[pos=-0.1]{S};
  \end{scope}
  % Right-override
  \begin{scope}[shift={(10,-3)},rotate=90]
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,-2.5) --(3,-2.5)--(3,0);
    \draw (0.25,-2.25)--(1.5,-1)--(2.75,-2.25)--cycle;
  \end{scope}
  % Right-coil
  \begin{scope}[shift={(12.5,-3)},rotate=90]
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,-2.5) --(3,-2.5)--(3,0);
    \draw (0,-1.5)--(3,-1);
  \end{scope}
  % some connection lines..  %%%% Wait with these until you have all coodinates to connections %%%%%%%%%%%
  % \draw[green](2,1.5)--(2,4)--(20,4);
  % \draw[green](3,1.5)--(3,3)--(18,3)--(18,-7)--(20,-7);
  % \draw[green](3.75,-4.25)--(3.75,-5.5);
  % Vertical-2wayPiston
  \begin{scope}[shift={(20,-12.5)}]
    \draw (1,5) -- (1,19) -- (5,19) -- (5,5) -- (1,5);
    \draw (0,17) -- (1,17) coordinate[pos=0](UpperConnection);    %%% New coordinate
    \draw (0,6) -- (1,6) coordinate[pos=0](LowerConnection);    %%% New coordinate
    \filldraw (1,15) rectangle (5,16);
    \filldraw[fill=white] (2.9,15) rectangle (3.1,1);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(20,-12.5)}]
    \draw[{Triangle}-{Triangle},line width = 0.1cm] (7,10)--node[pos=1.1]{OPEN}(7,15);
  \end{scope}
  % Vertical-speedControl
  \begin{scope}[shift={($(RedArrowEnd) + (0,-5)$)},scale=0.75]%[shift={(3.75,-9)},scale=0.75]
    \draw (0,4)--(0,3) coordinate[pos=0](SpeedControl);  %%% New coordinate
    \draw (0,1)--(0,0);
    \draw (1,0.5) arc (-90:-270:0.9 and 1.5);
    \draw (-1,0.5) arc (-90:90:0.9 and 1.5);
    \draw [-{Triangle}](-1,1) -- (1,3);
  \end{scope}
  %%% Green stuff
  \draw[green] (RedArrowEnd) -- (SpeedControl);
  \draw[green] (BlueArrow) |- (UpperConnection);
  \draw[green] (RedArrowStart) -- +(0,2) -| ($(LowerConnection)+(-1,0)$) -- (LowerConnection);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]